# Finder sorts by filename but in negative order - permanently

Tags: finder

All my finder windows are configured as list, sorting files by name. But for the files are sorted in inverse alphabetical order, while I'd like to have them in regular alphabetical order.
The view options allow only to specify which field to use for the sorting, but not which direction.

Is there a way to configure this?

Edit: By the answer I realised that I didn't specify that I'd like to have this as default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In Finder List view, move the pointer over the column name you want to sort by, then click it. Click the column name again to reverse the sort order.
[support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp1745/mac#:%7E:text=Click%20the%20column%20name%20again%20to%20reverse%20the%20sort%20order)

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the Finder window just above the listed contents are labels describing the name of each column (Name, Date Modified, etc.).

Click on the column header and the downward pointing arrow will change to an upward pointing arrow and re-sort the list view.